# What is the simplest way to asynchronously communicate between C++ and C# applications

Tags: c#, c++, messaging

I have a C++ application that needs to communicate to a C# application (a windows service) running on the same machine. I want the C++ application to be able to write as many messages as it wants, without knowing or caring when/if the C# app is reading them, or even if it's running. The C# app be able to should just wake up every now and then and request the latest messages, even if the C++ app has been shut down.

What is the simplest way to achieve this? I think this kind of thing is what MSMQ is for, but I haven't found a good way to do it in C++. I'm using Named Pipes right now, but that's not really working out as the way I'm doing it requires a connection between the two apps, and the C++ call to WriteLine blocks until the read takes place.

Currently the best solution I can think of is just writing the messages to a file with a timestamp on each message that the C# application checks periodically against its last update timestamp. That seems a little crude, though.

What is the simplest way to achieve this sort of messaging?

Comment: I was going to suggest the files mechanism as a crude but aimple and effective mechanism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the simplest way actually *is* using a file to store the messages. I would suggest using an embedded database like SQLite, though: the advantage will be better performance and a nice way to query for changes (i.e. SELECT * FROM messages WHERE timestamp > last_app_start).

Comment: Better performance than what? Than appending to the file in the writer app, and doing a seek to last-used read position at startup, followed by reads, in the reader app? Admittedly, the reader would also have to periodically lock the file to empty it.

Comment: SQLite looks like the way to go. It's remarkably easy to use, and it gives me the flexibility that I need, and a simplicity that I appreciate.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a named pipe.

Answer (score 0):

MSMQ definitely sounds like what you want, or the more basic reading and writing files written to a common area but then you need to watch contention on the files.

[VC++ help on MSMQ](http://www.codersource.net/mfc/mfc-message-queueing/working-with-msmq-in-visual-c.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The requirement of both apps not always running at the same time but still being able to message each other definitely means you need a third component to store/queue messages. Whether you use a shared database/file or you write a third app that acts as a message store is up to you. Either way you will find sharing always causes contention.

Personally I would look at 0MQ before MSMQ but neither will solve your problem as is. An sqlite database would be my first choice.